# sql to sum rows of booleans into rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to do the following transformation in SQL:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|POLICY_1|POLICY_2|POLICY_3|
+--------+--------+--------+
|T       |T       |F       |
+--------+--------+--------+
|F       |T       |F       |
+--------+--------+--------+
|T       |T       |T       |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Is it possible to query this table and end up with a result set that looks like:

```
+------+-----+
|POLICY|COUNT|
+------+-----+
|1     |2    |
+------+-----+
|2     |3    |
+------+-----+
|3     |1    |
+------+-----+
```

I'm wondering in general SQL terms, but incase it matters I'm using Postgres (9.2)

Comment: Make a pivot for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Union All, Aggregate and CASE Version**

```
 select 1 as POLICY, SUM(case when POLICY_1 = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as COUNT
  from POLICIES
  union all
 select 2 as POLICY, SUM(case when POLICY_2 = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as COUNT
  from POLICIES
  union all
 select 3 as POLICY, SUM(case when POLICY_3 = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as COUNT
  from POLICIES
```

**Unpivot Version: **(MicroSoft T-SQL specific)
If you insist, to convert a row to columns, you can use PIVOT/UNPIVOT functionality.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PolicyName) AS Row, * 
 FROM ( select SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_1 = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Policy_1,
               SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_2 = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Policy_2,
               SUM(CASE WHEN Policy_3 = 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Policy_3
        from POLICIES
      )p
 UNPIVOT ( T_Count FOR PolicyName  in ([Policy_1], [Policy_2], [Policy_3]))unpvt
```

**Unnest version** ( postgre sql specific )
All credits go to **Francis**, topic caster, i just post it here.

```
select
    UNNEST((select array_agg(generate_series) 
            from generate_series(1,3))) as policy_name,
    UNNEST(array[
             sum(case when policy_1 = 't' then 1 else 0 end),
             sum(case when policy_2 = 't' then 1 else 0 end),
             sum(case when policy_3 = 't' then 1 else 0 end)
           ]) as count from POLICY
```

Comment: the first part of your answer is a solution, but to be honest I was hoping there was another way.  Ideally, the query wouldn't have to change based on how many columns there were.  I'm going to leave the question open for a bit incase there are other suggestions.

Comment: The other way is PIVOT/UNPIVOT, but it's **not** ANSI SQL compatible. Fortunally for you, postgresql supports PIVOT and Row_Number. I am not familiar with postgresql, this example is working with MicroSoft T-SQL. You may need some tweaking to adapt it to postgre, though.

Comment: I've used UNNEST for this in Postgres, it's at least 3x quicker than the UNION ALL approach in my case

Comment: Would be good, if u add your solution, so ppl who google for your question, see your solution too. MS and FireBird have no **UNNEST** , so i can't generate example

Comment: @TPAKTOPA: since when does Postgres support PIVOT or UNPIVOT ? (Btw the names are Microsoft or Firebird, not MicroSoft or FireBird)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested,
here is the UNNEST version for Postgresql:

```
select
    UNNEST((select array_agg(generate_series) from generate_series(1,3))) as policy_name,
    UNNEST(array[
        sum(case when policy_1 = 't' then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case when policy_2 = 't' then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case when policy_3 = 't' then 1 else 0 end)
    ]) as count from POLICY
```